# Blur background behind item of ListView

Tags: android

I need to make **blur** **effect** behind items of a `listview`. Desired effect is shown below

[image]

The problem is that I need a very fast solution so that the items can scroll fast.

Comment: Hi, did you implemented this? I also want to implement this. The main problem I see is that, when we scroll the background of the items will change. The background doesn't remain same. Hence, we need to blur the background of item every millisecond. How did you solved your problem? Can you please post your code here?

Comment: Kindly reply to my above comment. How did you implemented this?

Comment: Hi, I didn't implement this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this blog post detailing a few different options.

http://nicolaspomepuy.fr/blur-effect-for-android-design/

and the github project here https://github.com/PomepuyN/BlurEffectForAndroidDesign

Interesting class found here.

```
package com.npi.blureffect;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.renderscript.Element;
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;
import android.util.Log;

public class Blur {

    private static final String TAG = "Blur";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public static Bitmap fastblur(Context context, Bitmap sentBitmap, int radius) {

        if (VERSION.SDK_INT > 16) {
            Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

            final RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
            final Allocation input = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, sentBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,
                    Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
            final Allocation output = Allocation.createTyped(rs, input.getType());
            final ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
            script.setRadius(radius /* e.g. 3.f */);
            script.setInput(input);
            script.forEach(output);
            output.copyTo(bitmap);
            return bitmap;
        }

        // Stack Blur v1.0 from
        // http://www.quasimondo.com/StackBlurForCanvas/StackBlurDemo.html
        //
        // Java Author: Mario Klingemann <mario at quasimondo.com>
        // http://incubator.quasimondo.com
        // created Feburary 29, 2004
        // Android port : Yahel Bouaziz <yahel at kayenko.com>
        // http://www.kayenko.com
        // ported april 5th, 2012

        // This is a compromise between Gaussian Blur and Box blur
        // It creates much better looking blurs than Box Blur, but is
        // 7x faster than my Gaussian Blur implementation.
        //
        // I called it Stack Blur because this describes best how this
        // filter works internally: it creates a kind of moving stack
        // of colors whilst scanning through the image. Thereby it
        // just has to add one new block of color to the right side
        // of the stack and remove the leftmost color. The remaining
        // colors on the topmost layer of the stack are either added on
        // or reduced by one, depending on if they are on the right or
        // on the left side of the stack.
        //
        // If you are using this algorithm in your code please add
        // the following line:
        //
        // Stack Blur Algorithm by Mario Klingemann <mario@quasimondo.com>

        Bitmap bitmap = sentBitmap.copy(sentBitmap.getConfig(), true);

        if (radius < 1) {
            return (null);
        }

        int w = bitmap.getWidth();
        int h = bitmap.getHeight();

        int[] pix = new int[w * h];
        Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
        bitmap.getPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);

        int wm = w - 1;
        int hm = h - 1;
        int wh = w * h;
        int div = radius + radius + 1;

        int r[] = new int[wh];
        int g[] = new int[wh];
        int b[] = new int[wh];
        int rsum, gsum, bsum, x, y, i, p, yp, yi, yw;
        int vmin[] = new int[Math.max(w, h)];

        int divsum = (div + 1) >> 1;
        divsum *= divsum;
        int dv[] = new int[256 * divsum];
        for (i = 0; i < 256 * divsum; i++) {
            dv[i] = (i / divsum);
        }

        yw = yi = 0;

        int[][] stack = new int[div][3];
        int stackpointer;
        int stackstart;
        int[] sir;
        int rbs;
        int r1 = radius + 1;
        int routsum, goutsum, boutsum;
        int rinsum, ginsum, binsum;

        for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                p = pix[yi + Math.min(wm, Math.max(i, 0))];
                sir = stack[i + radius];
                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);
                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);
                rsum += sir[0] * rbs;
                gsum += sir[1] * rbs;
                bsum += sir[2] * rbs;
                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }
            }
            stackpointer = radius;

            for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {

                r[yi] = dv[rsum];
                g[yi] = dv[gsum];
                b[yi] = dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (y == 0) {
                    vmin[x] = Math.min(x + radius + 1, wm);
                }
                p = pix[yw + vmin[x]];

                sir[0] = (p & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                sir[1] = (p & 0x00ff00) >> 8;
                sir[2] = (p & 0x0000ff);

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[(stackpointer) % div];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi++;
            }
            yw += w;
        }
        for (x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            rinsum = ginsum = binsum = routsum = goutsum = boutsum = rsum = gsum = bsum = 0;
            yp = -radius * w;
            for (i = -radius; i <= radius; i++) {
                yi = Math.max(0, yp) + x;

                sir = stack[i + radius];

                sir[0] = r[yi];
                sir[1] = g[yi];
                sir[2] = b[yi];

                rbs = r1 - Math.abs(i);

                rsum += r[yi] * rbs;
                gsum += g[yi] * rbs;
                bsum += b[yi] * rbs;

                if (i > 0) {
                    rinsum += sir[0];
                    ginsum += sir[1];
                    binsum += sir[2];
                } else {
                    routsum += sir[0];
                    goutsum += sir[1];
                    boutsum += sir[2];
                }

                if (i < hm) {
                    yp += w;
                }
            }
            yi = x;
            stackpointer = radius;
            for (y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                // Preserve alpha channel: ( 0xff000000 & pix[yi] )
                pix[yi] = (0xff000000 & pix[yi]) | (dv[rsum] << 16) | (dv[gsum] << 8) | dv[bsum];

                rsum -= routsum;
                gsum -= goutsum;
                bsum -= boutsum;

                stackstart = stackpointer - radius + div;
                sir = stack[stackstart % div];

                routsum -= sir[0];
                goutsum -= sir[1];
                boutsum -= sir[2];

                if (x == 0) {
                    vmin[y] = Math.min(y + r1, hm) * w;
                }
                p = x + vmin[y];

                sir[0] = r[p];
                sir[1] = g[p];
                sir[2] = b[p];

                rinsum += sir[0];
                ginsum += sir[1];
                binsum += sir[2];

                rsum += rinsum;
                gsum += ginsum;
                bsum += binsum;

                stackpointer = (stackpointer + 1) % div;
                sir = stack[stackpointer];

                routsum += sir[0];
                goutsum += sir[1];
                boutsum += sir[2];

                rinsum -= sir[0];
                ginsum -= sir[1];
                binsum -= sir[2];

                yi += w;
            }
        }

        Log.e("pix", w + " " + h + " " + pix.length);
        bitmap.setPixels(pix, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
        return (bitmap);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the link, I will try it. Implementing the blur effect not an issue, the main issue is to implement it for every item of listview and make it efficiently

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution if to fast compute a blurred version of the scaled-down background.

And then trim it every time the list is scrolled to apply small patches as the background of each item.

Answer (score 0):

I'm use this for create a blur image, also include a ansyctask for make that

/**
 * Created by Carlos Bedoy on 15/05/14.
 */

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.Element;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;
import android.view.View;

import org.pademobile.application.ApplicationLoader;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;


public class BlurService {

    public static BlurService instance;


    public static BlurService getInstance(){
        if(instance == null){
            instance = new BlurService();
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public Bitmap blurRenderScript(Bitmap smallBitmap)
    {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(smallBitmap.getWidth(), smallBitmap.getHeight(), smallBitmap.getConfig());
        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(ApplicationLoader.mainContext);
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        Allocation inAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, smallBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_GRAPHICS_TEXTURE);
        Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, output);
        script.setRadius(25);
        script.setInput(inAlloc);
        script.forEach(outAlloc);
        outAlloc.copyTo(output);
        rs.destroy();
        return output;
    }

    public Bitmap blurRenderScript(Bitmap smallBitmap, int radius)
    {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(smallBitmap.getWidth(), smallBitmap.getHeight(), smallBitmap.getConfig());
        RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(ApplicationLoader.mainContext);
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur script = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));
        Allocation inAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, smallBitmap, Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_GRAPHICS_TEXTURE);
        Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, output);
        script.setRadius(radius > 25 ? 25 : radius);
        script.setInput(inAlloc);
        script.forEach(outAlloc);
        outAlloc.copyTo(output);
        rs.destroy();
        return output;
    }
public Bitmap performRequestBlurByImage(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    DoAsyncBlur doAsyncBlur = new DoAsyncBlur();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        doAsyncBlur.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, bitmap);
    } else {
        doAsyncBlur.execute(bitmap);
    }
    try {
        return doAsyncBlur.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return bitmap;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        return bitmap;
    }
}

public Bitmap performRequestBlurByImageWithRadius(Bitmap bitmap, int radius)
{
    DoAsyncBlurWithRadius doAsyncBlur = new DoAsyncBlurWithRadius();
    doAsyncBlur.setRadius(radius);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        doAsyncBlur.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, bitmap);
    } else {
        doAsyncBlur.execute(bitmap);
    }
    try {
        return doAsyncBlur.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        return bitmap;
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        return bitmap;
    }
}

private class DoAsyncBlur extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap> {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
        return blurRenderScript(bitmaps[0]);
    }
}

private class DoAsyncBlurWithRadius extends AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap> {
    private int radius;

    public void setRadius(int radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... bitmaps) {
        return blurRenderScript(bitmaps[0], radius);
    }
}
```

}